# Spark Streaming Maintain stream data across batches

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-kafka, spark-streaming

I'm trying to build an etl pipeline using pyspark and kafka. I need to persist streams for future operations on them. I tried stateful streaming with updateStateByKey, and it works for a short time before spark unpersists the rdds (from the checkpoint), and tries to access them again and the app crashes with a FileNotFound exception. Below is my code:

```
        sc = SparkContext(conf=spark_conf)
        sc.setLogLevel("INFO")
        spark = SparkSession(sparkContext=sc)

        ssc = StreamingContext(sc, ssc_config['batchDuration'])

        config = getConfig()['kafka']
        kafka_stream = KafkaStream.create_source(ssc, config, "mytopic")
        new_msg = get_new_msg_stream(kafka_stream)
        transformed_msg = transform_msg(new_msg).updateStateByKey(updateState)

        ssc.checkpoint("./")
        ssc.start()
        ssc.awaitTermination()

        def updateState(new_state, old_state):
            if len(new_state) > 0:
               return new_state
            return old_state
```

I don't understand why this is happening or if using stateful streaming was a good idea for my use case because I need to maintain the state forever. Here is the driver stack trace:

```
JobScheduler:54 - Finished job streaming job 1524592150000 ms.0 from job set of time 1524592150000 ms
PythonRDD:54 - Removing RDD 60 from persistence list
BlockManager:54 - Removing RDD 60
CheckpointWriter:54 - Submitted checkpoint of time 1524592150000 ms to writer queue
CheckpointWriter:54 - Saving checkpoint for time 1524592150000 ms to file 'file:/home/jovyan/ampath/checkpoint-1524592195000'
SparkContext:54 - Starting job: runJob at PythonRDD.scala:141
DAGScheduler:54 - Got job 38 (runJob at PythonRDD.scala:141) with 1 output partitions
DAGScheduler:54 - Submitting ResultStage 46 (PythonRDD[138] at RDD at PythonRDD.scala:48), which has no missing parents
TaskSchedulerImpl:54 - Cancelling stage 46
DAGScheduler:54 - ResultStage 46 (runJob at PythonRDD.scala:141) failed in Unknown s due to Job aborted due to stage failure: Task creation failed: java.io.FileNotFoundException: File file:/home/jovyan/ampath/c1949961-34bc-4f6b-b846-247fb8f73ea4/rdd-60/part-00000 does not exist
java.io.FileNotFoundException: File file:/home/jovyan/ampath/c1949961-34bc-4f6b-b846-247fb8f73ea4/rdd-60/part-00000 does not exist at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.deprecatedGetFileStatus(RawLocalFileSystem.java:611)
```

Here is the definition of transform_msg method:

```
    def transform_msg(msg_stream):
    transformed_stream = msg_stream.transform(lambda rdd: transform(rdd))

    def transform(rdd):
        if not rdd.isEmpty():
            msg_df = rdd.toDF()
            transformed_msg = group_obs(msg_df).rdd
            return transformed_msg
    return transformed_stream

def group_msgs(obs_df):
    cols = [f.when(~f.col(x).isin("null"), f.col(x)).alias(x) for x in obs_df.columns if x != "obs_group_id"]

    obs = obs_df.select(*cols,"obs_group_id")

    grouped_by_obsgroup = filtered_obs_with_value\
                                    .withColumn("strObs", f.struct(f.col("obs_id"), f.col("obs_voided"),
                                    f.col("concept_id"), f.col("value"), f.col("value_type"), f.col("obs_date").alias("obs_datetime")))\
                                    .groupBy("obs_group_id", "encounter_id") \
                                    .agg(f.struct(f.col("obs_group_id"),f.collect_list("strObs").alias("obs")).alias("obs"))

    grouped_by_encounter = grouped_by_obsgroup \
        .groupBy("encounter_id")\
        .agg(f.to_json(f.collect_list(f.col("obs")).alias("obs")))

    return grouped_by_encounter
```

My aim is to have a look up which I can use to enrich my stream. Is there a better way to do this?
Any help would greatly be appreciated.

Comment: Can you post the driver stacktrace and definition of `transform_msg`? I can't see why Spark needs to retain batches older than t, t-1 in memory for what you're trying to do. Also if possible upgrade Spark and use `Structured Streaming` instead.

Comment: @maverik, thanks for your response. I have added the stacktrace and method definition in the question

Comment: Try setting `spark.streaming.unpersist` to false?

Comment: @maverik I will give that a shot. You mentioned structured streaming. Is there a different way I can achieve this using that?

Comment: Setting spark.streaming.unpersist to false worked. But I'm worried about long term memory usage of the application. Would structured streaming perform better?

Comment: You might benefit from studying this Structured Streaming [API](https://databricks.com/blog/2017/10/17/arbitrary-stateful-processing-in-apache-sparks-structured-streaming.html) although it's not yet available in Python.